# Rules not obeyed by if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

The below code is supposed to tell the user whether his input is a vowel or consonant or digit less than 1. The program however returns "Vowel" for all capital letters including consonants and whenever a digit is entered "Consonant" is returned. Ex - if a is entered, result = vowel. If b, result = Consonant. If B, result = Vowel (should be Consonant). If 1, result = Consonant(should be Digit) . Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
package checkVowelorConstantorNumber;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner inp = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean tf = false;


    while(tf == false) {
    System.out.println("Enter a character which is a - z or A - Z or 
    less than 1");
    char cha = inp.next().charAt(0);
    inp.nextLine();

    if(Character.isLetter(cha) && cha == 'a'||cha == 'e' || cha == 'i' || cha == 'o' || cha == 'u' || Character.isUpperCase(cha)) {
     System.out.println("Vowel");
    }
    else if(Character.isLetter(cha) && cha != 'a'|| cha != 'e' || cha != 'i' || cha != 'o' || cha != 'u' || Character.isUpperCase(cha)) {
     System.out.println("Consonant");
    }

    else if(Character.isDigit(cha) && cha <= 1 ) {
     System.out.println("Digit");
    }
    else  System.out.println("Invalid character");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: And `cha <= 1` is almost certainly not what you mean.

Comment: And note that `cha != 'a' || cha != 'e'` will always be `true`.

Comment: You need to spend some time [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) or with a pen and paper to figure out what your code is doing wrong and what it should look like. Walk though what each term of each if statement will do if you have a `B`, for example, and what the end result will be - that should make the problem fairly obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement first checks if the given character is a letter and not an a, 1 is neither so that is false, then it checks if 1 is not equal to 'e' causing that statement to be true, thus printing 'Consonant'. You have to make the check for isLetter for every comparison. Therefore i would recommend something like this:

```
if(Character.isLetter(cha)) {
   // Check for vowel or consonant based on letters
} else if(Character.isDigit(cha) && cha <= '1') {
   System.out.println("Digit");
} else {
   System.out.println("Invalid character");
}
```

You also should make the if statement for consonant use `&&` instead of `||`, since it should be none of the specified chars.

Answer (score 0):

Pay close attention to logical ands (`&&`), logical ors (`||`) and parentheses. Consider the following, modified from your code with some comments.

```
char cha = inp.next().charAt(0);
inp.nextLine();

if (cha.isLetter()) {
    // convert to uppercase to simplify the if
    char uc = cha.toUpperCase();
    if (uc == 'A' || uc == 'E' || uc == 'I' || uc == 'O' || uc == 'U') {
        // it's a vowel
    } else {
        // it's a letter that isn't a vowel (consonant)
    }
} else {
    // it's not a letter
    if (cha.isDigit() && cha < '1') {
        // but it is a digit less than 1
    } else {
        // it's something else (digit not less than '1' or not a digit)
    }
}
```